# How can I add unescaped text to an LXML Etree in Python?

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

LXML's builder [allows for easily generation of HTML and XML](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory), like this:

```
>>>from lxml.builder import E
>>>import lxml.etree
>>>lxml.etree.tostring(E.html('hello'))

b'<html>hello</html>'
```

But if I include text that's already in HTML, it escapes the angle brackets, as it should:

```
>>>lxml.etree.tostring(E.html('<b>Hello</b>'))                                                       
b'<html>&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;</html>'
```

So how can I get it to treat the inner text as raw HTML/XML? I'd like to get it to output `<html><b>Hello</b></html` in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by parsing your html string into an lxml etree object:

```
In [1]: from lxml.builder import E                                       

In [2]: import lxml.etree                                           

In [3]: lxml.etree.tostring(E.html(lxml.etree.fromstring('<b>Hello</b>')
Out[3]: b'<html><b>Hello</b></html>'
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't think about that. But this would require that the text I'm trying to insert is valid HTML/XML, no? I suspect that's not always the case with my data.

Comment: @Jonathan If it's not valid HTML then the fact that it gets urlencoded is correct behavior as otherwise you would end up with a malformed document.